# Email Validation Token as Request Parameter from URL

Tags: angular, validation, httprequest, frontend, token

I have created a form with which I want to reset a password. The BackEnd part is already finished, in the Front End I think a Validation Token has to be sent back. Can you show me how this works?

My code looks like this:

```js
 // login.service.ts
  resetPassword(loginUser: Login) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.baseUrl}/set-password`, loginUser, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).pipe(map(data => data)); }
```

```js
// reset-password.component.ts
  submitNewPassword() {
    this.submitted = true;

    //  stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.rpForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    const successText = 'Ihr Passwort wurde erfolgreich zurückgesetzt!';
    const errorText = 'Ihr Passwort konnte nicht zurückgesetzt werden!';
    this.rpAlertType = null;
    this.rpMessage = null;
    this.loginService.resetPassword(this.rpForm.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log('Password will be set!', data);
          this.submitted = false;

          if (data.success) {
            this.rpAlertType = 'success';
            this.rpMessage = successText;
          } else {
            this.rpAlertType = 'error';
            this.rpMessage = errorText;
          }
        },
        error => {
          this.submitted = false;
          this.alertType = 'error';
          this.rpMessage = errorText;
```

```js
ngOnInit() {
    // Reset password form
    this.rpForm = this.formBuilder.group( {
      password: ['', Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,}$')],
      confirm_password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will helps you!

```
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router' 
    export class GuestEventComponent implements OnInit {
     Id;
     constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.Id = params.id; // put your route file parameter insted of id
    console.log("ID", this.ID);

    })

   }

}
```

Comment: the function does not suffer. Why do I have to write in LocalStorage? I need a resetToken and I have to pass it on to the backend. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: what is validation token? I think you pass jwt token so i gave that answer.Can you tell me about validation token used in your function, so i can give another solution.

Comment: I don't think I explained my problem in detail. I made an area where the user can set a new password. In the form there is an input field for Password and Confirm Password. I think I need to set a resetToken and this should be sent to the BackEnd. At the moment I get the error missing params in the console!

Comment: In Console: Mail response {success: false, errorMessage: "missing params!"}errorMessage: "missing params!"success: false__proto__: Object

Comment: In BackEnd: where
        userentity0_.email_validation_code='null'

Comment: `{success: false, errorMessage: "missing params!"}
errorMessage: "missing params!"
success: false
__proto__: Object`

Comment: what you need on server side  accestoken or parameter ?

Comment: parameter is needed from Backend

Comment: ok so first of all you need to get token from url in your reset password component.ts file than upend that token with your form and pass it to server.

Comment: yeah, that´s exactly what i need to know. But I dont now how to get the token from the URL

Comment: try this code in your reset component and upend with your form

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean with this part: this.Id = params.id; // put your route file parameter insted of id. My Route ist in LoginService in the resetPassword()

Comment: i took one parameter as an id and set the value which get from params is upend with id.Measn which parameter you want to pass with your form, get from params and set it instead of params.id (instead of id).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

Here is my code for those who have the same problems and are in despair xD

How do I reset my password?

1.) create a login.service.ts and add the function:

```
resetPassword(resetPasswordValues: { password: string, token: string }) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.baseUrl}/your-api`, resetPasswordValues, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).pipe(map(data => data)); }
}
```

2.) paste the code into your reset-password.component.ts:

```
private token: string;
```

```
ngOnInit() {
// Send token
    this.token = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('token');
}
```

```
// Set new password
  submitNewPassword() {
this.loginService.resetPassword({ password, token: this.token})
}
```